# JavaScript - Mailto; CC, Subject area with entered textfield

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, adobe

I really need some expertise. I have developed a PDF Template with a button "SEND"; the purpose of this button is to send the entire template (PDF) to a certain email and a certain CC email. This is no problem to compute in Adobe X Pro. But, I also want to incorporate subject area in the email. This subject area must refer to a specific textbox in the template.

Example:

```
Mailto: "Test@test.com"
Cc: "test2@test.com"
Subject Test9010 (Generate from the entered data in the template).
```

Does anyone have a suitable solutions? I have searched Google and forums for solutions.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

To get the text value of a specific field in a PDF form, you'll need to know the field name and then you can use the document's getField method and then the value property of tyhat field. Also, "this" in Acrobat Javascript refers to the document context.

```
var enteredText = this.getField("myFieldName").value;
```

J-